# Roll a 6-sided die 5 times, record each number rolled and write a fraction for each number

Tags: probability

So I'm helping my son with his maths, and I'm totally lost! So we rolled a 6-sided die 5 times and we got the following numbers: 5,3,5,2,4.

Then it says to write a fraction for each number? I have no clue what the fraction would be or how to get it; does anyone have an idea?

Comment: if you dont know exactly the formulation of the exercise, how we can know it?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but I think they probably mean the fraction of times the number came up.

So $5$ came up twice out of the five rolls so its fraction is $\frac{2}{5}.$

$3$ came up once so, $\frac{1}{5}.$

1 came up zero times so $\frac{0}{5},$ etc.

Comment: Ok thank you so much I sorta thought that to but wasn't sure! Thanks again!!!!!!!!☺️